# Daly BMS connection error Ubuntu

Tags: communication, battery

I am trying to use an 8s daly BMS for my mobile robot and I am connecting it using the UART to USB converter provided by them. The connection works well on Windows, but when I connect the BMS to my computer with Ubuntu 20.04 the connection doesn't work, I tried checking the ports using `ls /dev/ttyUSB_BMS` and I see the port listed immediately after connecting the BMS, but after one second the port just disappears.

How can I fix this issue and have the BMS connected so I can communicate with it?

Comment: that's still a yes/no question ... edited it for you